weird string literal in goyacc action: is "ab\\\ncd" acceptable but "ab\ncd" NOT?
I came across this code in goyacc program, in cpyact function. When we see string literals that start with " or ', we just copy them. But the handling for "\\" and "\n" seems weird. Why we care about the "\\\n" sequence? Anything has to do with C string? Because goyacc is derived from Inferno's utils/iyacc/yacc.c
        case '\'', '"':
            // character string or constant
            match := c
            fcode.WriteRune(c)
            c = getrune(finput)
            for c != EOF {
                if c == '\\' {
                    fcode.WriteRune(c)
                    c = getrune(finput)
                    if c == '\n' { // does it mean "ab\\\ncd" is ok?
                        lineno++
                    }
                } else if c == match { 
                    break swt
                }
                if c == '\n' {// does it mean "ab\n" is NOT ok?
                    errorf("newline in string")
                }
                fcode.WriteRune(c)
                c = getrune(finput)
            }


The code doesn't mean "ab\\\ncd" is acceptable but "ab\n" is not. The first case has the form:
"ab\
cd"

and the second case has the form
"ab
cd"

a \ is required when the literal want a newline character.
